# Write a program to convert the time from 24 hours to 24 hours but the catch is everything must be a function from the input to the result

Tags: c++

so basically i am lost and i don't know where to go the original question says:
Write a program to convert the time from 24-hour notation to 12-hour notation and vice versa. Your program must be menu driven, giving the user the choice of converting the time between the two notations. Furthermore, your program must contain at least the following function: a function to convert the time from 24-hour notation to 12-hour notation, a function to convert the time from 12-hour notation to 24-hour notation, a function to display the choices, function(s) to get the input, and function(s) to display the results. (For 12-hour time notation, your program must display AM or PM.)

i figured out how to make it work but using less function than specified .. how can i make a separate function that has the output ?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void choice();
void inputincaseof24to12(int hours, int minutes);
void inputincaseof12to24(int hours, int minutes, char ampm);


int main()
{
    int hours = 1;
    int minutes = 0;
    char ampm = 0;
    char yourchoice;
    choice();
    cin >> yourchoice;

    if (yourchoice == 'A')
        inputincaseof24to12(hours, minutes);
    else if (yourchoice == 'B')
        inputincaseof12to24(hours, minutes, ampm);

}

void choice() {
    cout << "in case of conversion to 24 hours from 12 hours please enter 'A' " << endl;
    cout << "in case of comversion to 12 hours from 24 hours please enter 'B' " << endl;
}


void inputincaseof24to12 (int hours, int minutes) {

    cout << "Enter any number of Hours & Minutes to be converted from 24 hours Notation to 12 hours Notation " << endl;
    cin >> hours;
    cin >> minutes;

    if (hours < 12)
        cout << hours << " " << minutes << "A.M" << endl;
    else if (hours == 12)
        cout << hours << " " << minutes << "P.M" << endl;
    else if (hours > 12)
        cout << hours - 12 << " " << minutes << "P.M" << endl;

}



void inputincaseof12to24(int hours, int minutes, char ampm) {

    cout << "Enter any number of Hours & Minutes while considring the AM/PM [where 'A' stands for AM and 'P' stands for PM] state to be converted from 12 hours Notation to 24 hours Notation " << endl;
    cin >> hours;
    cin >> minutes;
    cin >> ampm;

    if (ampm == 'A' && hours <= 11)
        cout << hours << ":" << minutes;
    else if (ampm == 'P' && hours == 12)
        cout << 12 << ":" << minutes;
    else if (ampm == 'P' && hours > 12);
    cout << hours + 12 << ":" << minutes;
}
```

please do note i am still a noob in programing so go easy on me :) thank you

Comment: What is your problem.

Comment: At StackOverflow you ask a specific problem and get answers. We are not hear to write whole programs for you. See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for advice on asking questions on this site.

Comment: Define a structure for each form of notation.

Comment: Is there a `homework` tag?

Answer (score 1):

You need to ask a specific question, nobody here is going to do this assignment for you.  I do have some general advice to hopefully help guide you towards the answer.

1. Sanitize your inputs. When the user inputs their time values, make sure that they are actually numbers within the range you are looking for.  It's nice that you have a `std::cout` message requesting as such, but that's not going to make sure your users actually obey the rules.
2. Consolidate your I/O operations.  You've got calls to `std::cin` inside your functions that are already passing these arguments, and in fact the way you're doing it they are not passed by reference i.e. `int &hours` so even if the user puts usable values in they will go out of scope when your function returns.
3. Think about the logic used to convert 12 and 24 hour time formats. See this diagram for reference.  You will see why your current implementation logic for `conversionincaseB` is not quite right.

[image: 12 and 24 hour time]

4. You should come up with more descriptive names for your functions.  Nobody knows what `conversionincaseB` is supposed to do, but they might be able to infer what a more descriptive function name like `convert24HourTime` is supposed to do.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Mr Justin , i was just looking for advice not a block of code to copy and paste and you gave me just that :) also just for clarifying this is not a homework its an ungraded assignment / exersice

Comment: so i figured out how to work the program out but i am missing only one piece of the puzzle .. i am required to have a standalone function that outs the result .. in my new code i couted the answers from within the input function and i cant think of anything to do any help would be appreciated again :)

Comment: Remember what I said about passing by reference. You can modify your functions and when the values are set by `cin` the updated values are passed back to the caller.  Minimum example `int hours = 0;  void foo(int &hours) { hours = 7; }` now if you `cout << hours` after calling `foo(hours)` you will see 7.